# hg behind a local com through ssh?

Tags: mercurial, ssh, repository, firewall

I'm on a local com, not accessible from external network.
However, I can SSH to a remote server and transfer through SFTP.

I tried to do a hg clone from my local repo to the remote following this instructions: [How to clone repository to a remote server/repository with Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963040/how-to-clone-repository-to-a-remote-server-repository-with-mercurial)

It did create a repo on the remote server, however, no files were there.
I tried to do hg pull on the remote and it says `abort: repository default not found!`

Is there any way I can get hg to work through SSH with a com behind a firewall?

Answer (score 3):

Any machine you can reach via ssh you can clone or pull from and clone or push to.  Mercurial imposes no extra restrictions, so if you can get a shell you can do transport.

My guess is you've just botched your URL syntax, but unless you provide *the full text* of your inputs and outputs there's not much we can do to help.  In the general sense this is all you need to do:

On your local computer that can reach out but can't be reached from the outside and with your current working directory set to the **parent** of your local repository.

```
hg clone mylocalrepository ssh://you@remoteservername//absolute/path/on/remote/server
```

That takes your local repository (here named `mylocalrepository`) and creates a clone on a server (here named `remoteservername`) to which you're normally able to ssh (and get a real shell).  Notice that there is a double-slash **two** times.  That's requried to give an absolute path -- otherwise it's relative to your home directory on that machine.

If that doesn't do it for you please provide *exactly* the command you're running and the output you're getting along with examples of what does work to get a shell on that remote box.